# Running command prompt arguments by ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I want to run command prompt arguments using a **ASP.Net application**. I am using visual studio 2013.
Is it possible?

the followings are the command prompt commands I want to execute using MVC application to create and run a job in ***jenkins***

1. C:\Users\ .jenkins java -jar C:\Users.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\jenkins-    cli.jar -s http://localhost create-job myjob < C:\Users\Desktop\config.xml
2. C:\Users\ .jenkins java -jar C:\Users.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\jenkins-cli.jar  -s http://localhost / build myjob

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, you want to run these command line tools on thee webserver, right? Not on the client connecting to the web application.

If the former, it's pretty straightforward, make sure that you IIS application pool is running under a user account that is allowed to execute these tools and use the `Process` class together with the `ProcessStartInfo` class to invoke the commandline and wait for the results:

```
string jobname = jobNameFromInput;

if (!Regex.IsMatch(jobname, "^(\"[a-z0-9-_ ]+\"|'[a-z0-9-_ ]+'|[a-z0-9-_]+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
{
    throw SecurityException("Invalid job name");
}

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\Users.jenkins\java.exe");

string argumentTemplate = "-jar C:\\Users.jenkins\\war\\WEB-INF\\jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost / build {0}";

startInfo.Arguments =  string.Format(argumentTemplate, jobname);
Process.Start(startInfo);
Process.WaitForExit();
```

See:

- [Process.WaitForExit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0w4h05yb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: i just want to get the job name by user interaction.i want to change the name of the job by giving a name in a text box .i.e i want to dynamically  change  **myjob**  in the **arguments**.how can i do that?

Comment: it's just a string. So you can merge in values as you build the commandline. Make sure when accepting user data into the process invocation, that you scrub it thoroughly. So that people can't for example add `| deltree c:\windows` to it.

Comment: i am getting the following error in ("C:\Users \.jenkins\java.exe");
unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: Sorry I forgot to escape the `\`  in the strings. But these are *VERY* basic C# things you're asking me now. You should be able to resolve these yourself and edit my answer if needed.